# TypeCast using type / string name of class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have one variable `objDataModel` of type `UDataModel` Which is inheriting from `AbstractDataModel`

```
public class AbstractDataModel
{
    internal string SomeName { get; set; }
}
public class UDataModel: AbstractDataModel
{

}

public class FDataModel: AbstractDataModel
{

}


public class UCommandProcessor : AbstractCommandProcessor<UDataModel>
{

}
public class FCommandProcessor : AbstractCommandProcessor<FDataModel>
{

}
 public abstract class AbstractCommandProcessor<TDataModel> :SomeInterface<TDataModel>
  where TDataModel: AbstractDataModel
 {

 }
```

I have variable of type  of UDataModelType i.e.`var tDataModelType= typeOf(UDataModel)` using which I am able to create its object.

```
 var tDataModel = (AbstractDataModel)Activator.CreateInstance(tDataModelType);
```

I have variable of type UCommandProcessor i.e  `var processorType= typeOf(UCommandProcessor)` 
 I am able to create object of

```
 var processor = Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

but I am not able to TypeCast it into UCommandProcessor
  When I tried

```
var processor = (AbstractCommandProcessor<AbstractDataModel>)Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

I am getting exception of

> Unable to cast object of type 'ABC.Domain.UCommandProcessor' to type
>   'ABC.Common.Contract.AbstractCommandProcessor`1[ABC.Common.Contract.AbstractDataModel]'.

Is there any method like

```
 var processor = (AbstractCommandProcessor<typeOf(tDataModel )>)Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

Even I Cant do like

```
 var processor = (AbstractCommandProcessor<typeOf(tDataModel )>)Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

Comment: Is `UserDataModel` supposed to be `UDataModel` or are those two different types?

Comment: updated question, sorry for confusion caused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast can't work, if you cast to `AbstractCommandProcessor<AbstractDataModel>` you are basically needing covariance, which is only supported for interfaces and delegates. In this line:

```
(AbstractCommandProcessor<AbstractDataModel>)Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

The cast might as well be a `AbstractCommandProcessor<FDataModel>` which clearly isn't valid. I would suggest making an abstract class `AbstractCommandProcessor` from which the generic version derives, then you can just cast to the non-generic version:

```
public abstract class AbstractCommandProcessor {}

public class AbstractCommandProcessor<T> : AbstractCommandProcessor, SomeInterface<T> 
                                           where T: AbstractDataModel

...
var processor = (AbstractCommandProcessor)Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

**Edit:** If you don't really need classes, you could make it work with interfaces and covariance:

```
public interface AbstractDataModel { }
public class UDataModel : AbstractDataModel { }
public class FDataModel : AbstractDataModel { }


public class UCommandProcessor : AbstractCommandProcessor<UDataModel> { }
public class FCommandProcessor : AbstractCommandProcessor<UDataModel> { }
public interface AbstractCommandProcessor<out TDataModel> : SomeInterface<TDataModel>
 where TDataModel : AbstractDataModel
{ }

public interface SomeInterface<out TDataModel> where TDataModel : AbstractDataModel { }

...

var processor = 
  (AbstractCommandProcessor<AbstractDataModel>)Activator.CreateInstance(processorType);
```

This will work because of covariance (the [`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/dd469487.aspx) keyword which means you can use something more derived than specified by the generic constraint).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander. I am using first option suggested by you.

Comment: I have one method 
public void LoadModel(T  Model) inside class 
public class AbstractCommandProcessor<T>, But after typecasting I am not able to call that method as AbstractCommandProcessor don't have that method. :(

Comment: @RoshanGhangare Why not implement `public abstract void LoadModel(AbstractDataModel model);` in the abstract base class? In the derived class you'll have: `public override void LoadModel(AbstractDataModel model)` and in the method you can cast the model to T: `LoadModel(AbstractDataModel model) {  T derivedModel = (T)model;  .... }`